# jQuery: Adjust layout on resize window. Odd bug?

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize

I have a center floating website and placed 2 bars on the side to cover any images that go outside of the `#main_container`.

```
<style>
#main_container{
display:block;
width:1024px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
</style>

<div style="background:#000; z-index:100; position:absolute; height:100vh;" id="side-l"></div>
<div style="background:#000; z-index:100; position:absolute; height:100vh;" id="side-r"></div>
<div id="main_container">
<!-- body -->
</div>
```

I use jQuery to resize the width of the `#side-l`, and the width and left of `#side-r`.
The page works great when it loads and added a `$(window).resize` so when the page is resized the side bars are readjusted. When the windows size is increased everything works but when the window is decreased, everything is off by about 10px too small. If I increase the size of the window by just 1px everything is adjusted correctly. When I decrease the windows size, it does not matter if by 1px or 1000px. The sidebars are off by the same amount. Only resizing bigger and onload, works properly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    adjust();

    function adjust(){
        screenwidth=$( window ).width()
        sidewidth=(screenwidth-1024)/2

        $( "#side-l" ).css("width",sidewidth)
        $( "#side-r" ).css("width",sidewidth)
        $( "#side-r" ).css("left",screenwidth-sidewidth)
    }

    $( window ).resize(function() { adjust();adjust(); });
})
```

If I call the `adjust()` function twice when resizing, it works even for resizing smaller. Anyone have an idea of why it breaks only when resizing smaller? Any fix suggestions so I don't have to call the function twice to make it work properly?

FireFox 33.1 and Chrome 38.0.2125.111 m

Comment: When you make the window smaller do you see scrollbars flash? If you do it's possible that your function is calculating based on the reduced size with scrollbars. Once the elements are resized the scrollbars would go away since everything fits in the window again.

Comment: not sure i understand or see the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/p0Le9hm1/ - i tried removing the `adjust()` function inside `resize` but didn't see a difference in behaviour...